# Use induction to prove that the complete graph on n points has exactly n(n - 1)/2 lines.

Tags: graph-theory

I found this problem in Abstract Alebra textbook in induction section.I never prove by induction on something like polygon
Anyone can give me a hint for this problem?

Comment: Something is wrong with the title because $n(n-1) = 2$ is an equation

Comment: There's a lot of literature on the _handshake problem_: https://www.google.com/search?q=handshake+problem&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 2):

Consider n+1 points, select one particular point A and divide the lines in two sets : the ones which involve A and the ones who don't. You can easily number the ones which involve A, and the induction  hypothesis gives you the number of one that don't. Hope this helps.

Comment: Another more direct way to calculate this is :
a line is uniquely defined by two points, thus there are as many lines as different couple of points, ie ${n \choose 2} = {n(n-1)\over 2}$